# Duplicated and Missing Values in Vertica Time Series Analytics Query

Tags: sql, oracle, time-series, vertica

currently I am facing a problem with genereting a list of dates at a specific start date in Vertica.
Based on this article [https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/240532/use-time-series-analytics-to-generate-a-list-of-dates-at-a-specific-start-date](https://stackoverflow.com) I used get the data I wanted.
But recently, out of nowhere, my query generated dupblicate dates (months) and the last month (march) is missing completly.

My query:

```
SELECT
        LEFT(ADD_MONTHS((EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ts::DATE) || '-' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ts::DATE) ||
'-01')::DATE, 1)::varchar, 7) as validity_month
    FROM (
        SELECT ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE(), -36)::TIMESTAMP as tm -- take the last 36 months
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT CURRENT_DATE()::TIMESTAMP
    ) as t TIMESERIES ts as '1 MONTH' OVER (ORDER BY t.tm) -- build a timeseries for every month
```

The last 36 months until January 2023 just work fine and provide the data series I needed.
Starting from January 2023 I get the following data:

| validity_month |
| --- |
| '2023-01' |
| '2023-01' |
| '2023-02' |
| '2023-04' |
| '2023-04' |

March is missing and I get duplicated values. Does anyone have a clue what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thanks alot and best regrads!

Tried to change the query and expected I would generate a data series starting from a given month until today without missing and duplicated months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem with month-long intervals, try using `TIMESERIES` just to get a series of integers, then `CROSS JOIN` with that int list, and use `ADD_MONTHS()` :

```
WITH
  monthcount(monthcount) AS (SELECT 6) -- take the last 6 months
, lim(dt) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE(), -monthcount),'MONTH') FROM monthcount
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),'MONTH')
)
, ts(ts) AS (
  SELECT ts FROM lim
  TIMESERIES ts as '1 MONTH' OVER (ORDER BY dt::TIMESTAMP) 
) 
, i(i) AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ts) FROM ts) 
, minmonth(minmonth) AS (SELECT MIN(dt) FROM lim)
SELECT
  ADD_MONTHS(minmonth,i) AS validity_month
, i
FROM i CROSS JOIN minmonth CROSS JOIN monthcount
WHERE i <= monthcount
ORDER BY 1
;
```

| validity_month | i |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | 1 |
| 2022-12-01 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 | 3 |
| 2023-02-01 | 4 |
| 2023-03-01 | 5 |
| 2023-04-01 | 6 |

Comment: Hey Marco, thanks so much for the help! It worked very well and fixex my problem! I wish I could give an upvote but unfortunately I'm to new.. best regards!

Answer (score 0):

It's because, in the `TIMESERIES` clause, `'1 MONTH'` is equivalent to `'30 DAYS'`.
See this query (I fixed your expression to return the 1st of the month following the input date - don't use string operations!) - with both the expression for `validity_month` and the input date value - for the last 6 months:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ts,'MONTH'),1),'YYYY-MM') AS validity_month
, ts::DATE AS real_date
FROM (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE(), -6)::TIMESTAMP as tm -- take the last 6 months
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE()::TIMESTAMP
) as t 
-- build a timeseries for every month
TIMESERIES ts as '1 MONTH' OVER (ORDER BY t.tm);
```

Result:

| validity_month | real_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11 | 2022-10-02 |
| 2022-12 | 2022-11-01 |
| 2023-01 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2023-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| 2023-02 | 2023-01-30 |
| 2023-04 | 2023-03-01 |
| 2023-04 | 2023-03-31 |

3th January + 30 days is 1st of March; 1st of March + 30 days is 31st of March. `ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(DATE '2023-03-01','MONTH),1)` and `ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(DATE '2023-03-31','MONTH),1)` both return 1st April.